# How do I center a GridView in its LinearLayout parent?

Tags: android, layout, gridview, android-linearlayout

GridView is not behaving like it is supposed to.
This [screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/37403003@N08/3994585989/) shows that the GridView (in landscape mode) is flushed left.
I want it centered.

This is the XML layout for the GridView.

```
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/templatelandscape"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<GridView 
  android:id="@+id/commandsbarlandscape"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1.0"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:padding="0dp"
  android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
  android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
  android:numColumns="auto_fit"
  android:columnWidth="52dp"
  android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
  android:gravity="fill_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You need GridView to be centered or its items???

Comment: I want the GridView to be centered in its parent. Not the items.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you resolved your problem (i hope yes, and also i'm very late on answering on this post!), but here is a clue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidth" >

    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Unfortunately this work only if there is 1 content on the grid.
Maybe someone can improve it!

Answer (score 1):

1. `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` has no meaning for widgets that have their own scrolling, like `GridView`.
2. `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` are for `RelativeLayout`, not `LinearLayout`.

Get rid of your `android:layout_weight="1.0"`, change your `android:layout_height` to `"fill_parent"` or a specific height, change the `LinearLayout` to a `RelativeLayout`, and you may be in better shape.

Answer (score 1):

set the value of LinearLayout with following attribute

`android:gravity="center"`.

and remove the following line from gridview

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to RelativeLayout and remove the horizontal padding from the grid view.  Horizontal padding was causing my grid to shift off of center.  I added a view container around the grid item layout to create the padding.

Answer (score 0):

Your GridLayout should be like this..

```
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/templatelandscape"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
<GridView 
  android:id="@+id/commandsbarlandscape"
  android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1.0"
  android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
  android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
  android:numColumns="auto_fit"
  android:columnWidth="52dp"
  android:stretchMode="none"
  android:gravity="fill_horizontal" />
```

I just place android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" in parent layout so it set gridlayout in it's parent center but not it's content in center as you want.
Also added  android:layout_width="0dp" because it's equals to ""warp_content" property if you give "0dp" it will show you better result. 
I also removed that relative layout attributes you added you can observe, if your not using RelativeLayout then it's meaningless to use that properties that do nothing.

For testing purpose you can check that it's working correctly or not just test using following xml code

```
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/templatelandscape"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
<GridView 
  android:id="@+id/commandsbarlandscape"
  android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
  android:layout_width="300dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1.0"
  android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
  android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
  android:numColumns="auto_fit"
  android:columnWidth="52dp"
  android:stretchMode="none"
  android:gravity="fill_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The above xml shows you that your grid layout comes in center in parent but not it's content.

Hope this explanation works for you...

Comment: you can also make use of RelativeLayout it's pretty good , but that doesn't matter for your problem..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the GridView in the LinearLayout, set it in the **RelativeLayout** and 
set the **layout_centerHorizontal=true** and **layout_centerVertical=true** in the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found is doing this by code.

This is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f1f1f1"
android:orientation="vertical">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/radio_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/gridview_column_space"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/gridview_column_space"
    android:columnWidth="@dimen/gridview_column_width"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/gridview_column_space"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/gridview_column_space"
    android:stretchMode="none"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    />

<include layout="@layout/placeholder" />
```

And this is the code that do the magic on my fragment:

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mGridView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Point point = Common.getScreenSize(getActivity());

                int rowSpace = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.gridview_column_space);
                int rowWidth = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.gridview_column_width) + rowSpace;

                int minWith = (point.x / rowWidth) * rowWidth;
                int padding = (point.x - minWith) / 2;
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(minWith + padding * 2, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);


                mGridView.setPadding(padding + rowSpace / 2, 0, padding, 0);
                mGridView.setLayoutParams(params);

                mGridView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        } 

    }); } 
}
```

Comment: sir what is the Common  class?